# Symmetric caching mechanism

Tags: php, caching

I have designed a tiny PHP framework for one of my customers 2 years ago, To make this system faster I implement a simple PHP page caching mechanism.

This simple mechanism require an interval value and compare it with the last time of page modified time, like the following example:

```
$interval = 5 * 3600;
$filename = ....

if ( file_exists($filename) && (time() - $interval) < filemtime($filename) ) {
    readfile($filename);
    exit();
}

// Rest of the code
```

Now, according to my customer request I have to make few changes in this Framework and one of the important things in this list is my `Caching-System`.

My customer says that current mechanism doesn't work symmetrically - e.g assuming that website home-page and category-page follow the above mechanism, Now if my customer add a new item in homepage, the item will first shown in category page and then shown in homepage if both page get expired in two different times.

Is there any way to make this mechanism symmetric without using any external library?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about clearing all cached items whenever a content update happens ? Easy, short and safe.

Comment: I agree with your comment but some contents in these pages need to refreshed everyday and maybe administrator makes no update for a week!

Comment: as @JoniSalmi wrote, this wouldn't replace your current system in any way, but rather complete it to handle manual updates gracefully (you don't want to wait 5 hours to get the new content online).

Comment: @JoniSalmi Thanks, Very convincing :-)